# Filemaker report

Tags: ms-access, filemaker

I am presently converting an access file to a filemaker solution and very new to filemaker.

In Microsoft access, I have a report that displays the output of a query which in turns queries information from a table. How should I build that in filemaker?

Answer (score 1):

FileMaker is different in that views (called layouts in FileMaker), which display query results, are defined prior to use. For example, if you had a Customer table, and you wanted to find out which customers are in a specific city, you would would first create a new layout that displayed the fields you would want to see in the result, perhaps company name, city, contact person and phone.

Once you have the layout ready, you can either manually query the table directly in the layout using query-by-example. The specific steps would be:

1. From the View menu, choose Find Mode.
2. Click in the city field and type in the city you're searching for, ex. San Francisco.
3. Use the Requests menu and choose Perform Find, or just click the perform Find button in the status area at the top of the window.

A couple of points:

1. You can enter search criteria in as many fields as you like, result in an 'AND' search. For example, you could search for customers in San Francisco and that have a contact named Jorge.
2. To do an OR search, you need to add additional 'find requests' by using the Requests menu and choosing Add New Request.
3. In text fields, searches are by default 'begins with' searches. For example if you had a contact named Jorge, that contact would come up in a search for Jorge, Jor, or even J. If you need a whole word match, preface your criteria with =, ex =Jorge
4. Take a look at the search operators at the top of the screen where it says Insert: Operators. This option is only available in Find Mode. You'll find you can search for date ranges or wildcard characters, pretty much anything you need.
5. If this is a query you need frequently, such as a monthly aging report, the search can be encoded into a script and tied to a button, so that next time you need the report, you just push the button.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a programming question. Go To Layout mode and select Layout/New Layout Report from the menu. The wizard will guide you through  generating the report. You will need to add a script to search for you data.

The best way to learn this is to create one of the starter solutions and see how reports work there

Answer (score 0):

You can find a set of records using any layout that has the field(s) you want to search, regardless of its primary purpose. The found records will be displayed using that layout or you can switch to another layout, say a report layout.

After you have created ( or duplicated an existing Access layout ) the user can simply type Command+F and enter the city name in the city field. You can make this field a popup field in find mode to make it easier. Select or enter the city name and press enter.

Filemaker is so flexible that there are a great many ways to accomplish the Find but your users are probably familiar with entering the name in the report layout.

Always test your ideas with a number of users so as to keep them happy.